# Function that mimics remove from standard template library doesn't work correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, range

In the CS class in college we have been given the assignment to write several function templates that mimic the functionality of those in the standard library. I've tested all of them and they all work, except for the last one the "remove" function.

```
template <typename T> 
T* remove(T *left, T *right, T &item)
{
  T *element = left; // Need a pointer to the element we are manipulating
  int GoAhead;   // How much in advance is the next element to check
  T *finalElement = right; // The new final pointer of the array.

  while(element < right)
  {
    if(*element == item)
    {
      GoAhead = 0;
      while(element + GoAhead < finalElement)
      {
        T *tempElement = element + GoAhead;
        *tempElement = *(tempElement + 1);
        ++GoAhead;
      }
      --finalElement;
    }
    ++element;
  }
  return finalElement;
}
```

It works well when the arrays are small, but when the array has many elements (In the test we are given arrays of 100000 elements) for some reason it misses some of the elements it should erase. I don't really understand why this happens. 
Can someone point me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: should the `while(element < right)` be instead `while(element < finalElement)` so that if elements are removed, the end will adjusted?

Comment: I tried both ways and they give the same result. And I think while(element < finalElement) is a little bit faster as it only copies everything until the new ending.

Comment: Another problem is that you should test the new current item for equality rather than incrementing to the next in case you have two or more matching items one right after the other.

Comment: So, Should I test it and copy the elements again before continuing?

Comment: probably easiest would be to make the increment of `element` to be in an `else` so that it is incremented only when `*element != item` and make the change to `while(element < finalElement)` to end the loop when everything has been moved up.  I think that would do it.  It still seems pretty inefficient to me with too much moving.  See the answer below for another insight.

Comment: It works now, but it still fails with one of the tests, so Im going to try with the answer below.

Comment: Well I don't really know if it's failing or going too slow and I don't have the patience to wait for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function didn't work for [2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2], not to mention an array of 100000 elements. If you are really mimic those in the standard library, it would be much simpler by replacing the elements that compare equal to val by the next element that does not, and signaling the new size of the shortened range by returning an pointer to the element that should be considered its new past-the-end element:

```
template <typename T> 
T* remove(T *left, T *right, const T &item) // you didn't modify the item, so add a const before it
{
    T* result = left;
    while (left!=right) {
        if (!(*left == item)) {
            *result = *left;
            ++result;
        }
        ++left;
    }
    return result;
}
```

it returns an pointer to the new end of that range.